# Dúvida na consulta SQL "between" ou "in"

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou gerando um relatório entre data, conforme a figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, quando entro com a data inicial:

**Ano inicial:** 2014 **Mês inicial:** 6 
e

**Ano final:** 2015  **Mês final:** 5

não traz os dados, a consulta interpreta que *mês inicial* 6 é maior que *mês final* 5.

Caso eu utilizar a cláusula `IN` a consulta retorna apenas os meses 6 e 5 e não retornando o mês 4, porém quando utilizado o `BETWEEN` não retorna nenhum dado.

Segue a consulta.

**BETWEEN**

```
WHERE v.verba_ano BETWEEN $ano AND $ano_fnal AND v.verba_mes BETWEEN $mes AND $mes_fim
```

**IN**

```
$WHERE= "WHERE v.verba_ano IN($ano,$ano_fnal) AND v.verba_mes IN($mes,$mes_fim)";
```

Comment: É em PHP, certo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz assim (se for php e mysql)

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', v.verba_ano, v.verba_mes), "%Y-%m") BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('{$ano}-{$mes}', "%Y-%m") AND STR_TO_DATE('{$ano_fim}-{$mes_fim}', "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: obrigado pela contribuição Adir Kuhn

Comment: Se minha resposta for a certa para seu problema marque como solução, tks

Answer (score 2):

O `BETWEEN` espera que o primeiro parâmetro seja menor que o segundo, o que causa o seu problema.

Utilizar o `IN` também não resolve seu problema porque ele não trabalha com intervalos, mas sim com valores isolados. Ex: `data IN (3,8)` não irá trazer o intervalo 3 a 8, mas sim **exatamente** os valores 3 e 8

**Solução**

Altere sua consulta para selecionar a data completa, no formato `AAAA-MM-DD`.

Procure sempre armazene no seu banco colunas de datas com o tipo `DATE`.

O dia você pode gerar dinamicamente a partir da query:

```
SELECT * FROM tabA
WHERE verba_data BETWEEN '{$ano}-{$mes}-01' AND last_day('{$ano_fnal}-{$mes_fim}-01');
```

Segue um exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6859c/1).

Comment: gmsantos, uma duvida, testando aqui, encontrei um erro, seguinte: quando eu insiro a ano inicial: 2014 e o mês inicial: 06 e o ano final: 2015 e o mês final 05, a consulta não retorna nada por que o mês inicial é maior que o mês final 05 ... alguma outra alternativa ? obrigado

Comment: @hulckb você juntou a data em somente um campo ? é do tipo date?

Comment: gmsantos, ajuntei conforme o seu esquema '{$ano}-{$mes}-01' AND last_day('{$ano_fnal}-{$mes_fim}-01'); o tipo do campo func_ano é INT e o tipo do func_mes é TINYINT

Comment: Você precisa juntar os campos func_ano com func_mes para um novo campo do tipo data, assim você estará fazendo do jeito correto. O MySQL como outro banco de dados tem tipos de dados para datas,

Comment: eu já ajuntei gmsantos, tem um exemplo ai ? abraços

Comment: Coloquei no corpo da resposta, último link

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24987/discussion-between-gmsantos-and-hulckb).

Answer (score 1):

Tenta algo assim, comigo funcionou.

```
WHERE (v.verba_ano BETWEEN $ano AND $ano_fnal) AND (v.verba_mes BETWEEN $mes AND $mes_fim)
```

Comment: Ola Pedro, tentei a sua dica e não deu certo, mesmo assim, muito obrigado por contribuir

Answer (score 1):

Comparar datas fica fácil se você inverter mes/ano para ano/mes em um único valor inteiro: No seu exemplo, 06/2014 a 05/2015 você compararia se a data está entre 201406 e 201505.

```
where (verba_ano * 100 + verba_mes) between 201406 and 201505
```

Onde 201406 = $ano*100+$mes e 201505 - $ano_fim*100+$mes_fim

Se precisar do dia também a formula fica

```
ano * 10000 + mes * 100 + dia
```

Answer (score 0):

Deu certo aqui, segue o código abaixo:

```
AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',i.func_ano,i.func_mes,'01'),'%Y-%m-%d')
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$ano-$mes-01','%Y-%m-%d') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('$ano_fnal-$mes_fim-01','%Y-%m-%d')
```